# New property from dll isn't recognized by Xamarin Studio

Tags: dll, xamarin.ios, xamarin, .net-assembly, xamarin-studio

I'm using a dll file (.NET-Assembly) in my project. This dll file is generated by another project which is also on my hard drive (managed with GIT). Now there has been added a new property to this dll file. If I want to use this property it is not in the autocomplete list and if I still want to use it it is in red. The project compiles without errors. Only when placing my mouse above the red property I get

> error CS0117: 'Library.myObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'myProperty'

I tried to restart Xamarin, recompile each project, restart the Mac, readded the dll file, tried different options (refresh, local copy, request specific version, ...) and none of them worked.

How can I get the new property appearing in my project?

Comment: Is it possible that the property isn't visible to outside (i.e. internal, private or something)? Are you sure you are referencing the correct assembly?

Comment: No it's definitively `public`. I'm navigating with Xamarin to the project. I only noticed that I had one time two projects in my last project list: one path had the folder in upper-case letters and the other in lower case letters. But I don't know if that makes a difference. Navigating with Finder only shows me one folder - so it should be the same. I don't know which other way exists to inspect the dll. If I open the other project I can see my property. Than I generate everything new and I reference it. So it should be the correct path. Is there a caching somewhere?